# how to download stock code with other data from yahoo using R

Tags: r, quantmod

```
##########################################
## Daily prices from Yahoo 
## thertrader@gmail.com - Nov. 2015
##########################################
library(quantmod)

startDate = "2000-01-01"
thePath = "D:\\daily\\data\\"
source(paste(thePath,"code\\listOfInstruments.r",sep=""))

for (ii in theInstruments){
 print(ii)
 data = getSymbols(Symbols = ii, 
                   src = "yahoo", 
                   from = startDate, 
                   auto.assign = FALSE)
 colnames(data) = c("open","high","low","close","volume","adj.")
 write.zoo(data,paste(thePath,ii,".csv",sep=""),sep=",",row.names=FALSE)

}
```

I am using the above code to download data from yahoo. The data I am getting from Yahoo doesn't include code . It has only date,close_price etc.
I also want to add stock code to the file
How can I do that?

Thanks in advance